# How to make EF Code First load "ICollection" properties, when calling DBSet<T>.Find(id)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I'm searching for a "list" like this  `DbSet<T>.Where(predicate)` I Can Add `.Include("xxx")` but that doesn't apply for a single object.

I can't figure out how to make EF load `virtual` `Icollection<T>` properties, when calling `DbSet<T>.Find(id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current API you can't do eager loading with the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

From P[erformance Considerations for Entity Framework 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

> What you have to consider when using the Find method is:
>
> ...
>
> Also, keep in mind that **Find only returns the entity you are looking
>   for and it does not automatically loads its associated entities** if
>   they are not already in the object cache. If you need to retrieve
>   associated entities, you can use a query by key with eager loading.

So the closest is what you can get is querying e.g using `SingleOrDefault`

```
dbSet.Include("xxx").SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id)
```

Or you can explicitly [load the related entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) after the find:

```
using (var context = new Db())
{
    var entity = context.SomeSet.Find(id);

    context.Entry(entity).Collection(p => p.SomeCollection).Load();
}
```

Comment: If I'd disable lazy loading, would that help ?

Comment: The problem with "Query" is that not all object have a common ancestor, or in other words, not all of them have "Id" as their Key

Comment: I know that Find has some advantages what you cannot workaround with a "Query" but this is how EF currently works. You can try to have an interface with the Key which is implemented by your entities...

Comment: OK, I guess I'm gonna head that path then. Thanx

Comment: I remembered a way to load explicitly collection after a find and I've found the article so I've updated my answer.